# How do I create a new column with the values contained inside all the parentheses in a row?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Column I want to extract the parentheses from :

```
   SktNo                         Description
0     19  WATER CALTROP (LING KOK) (CHN) K10
```

I initially was able to create a new column based on extracting the values in parentheses with this:

```
df['Origin'] = df['Description'].str.extract(r"\(([A-Za-z]+)\)", expand=False)
```

But that took the parentheses with the least number of letters in it and not both of them.

I want the new column to include both strings between the parentheses like this:

```
Origin 
LING KOK, CHN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.findall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.findall.html) + [`Series.str.join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.join.html):

```
df['Origin'] = df['Description'].str.findall(r'\((.*?)\)').str.join(', ')
```

Result:

```
   SktNo                         Description         Origin
0     19  WATER CALTROP (LING KOK) (CHN) K10  LING KOK, CHN
```